# Is there an assert for sublists in Python unit testing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

For Python 2.7:

```
list1 = [1, 2]

self.assertIn(1, list1)
self.assertIn(2, list1)
```

Is there a way I can do this easier? Something like:

```
self.assertIn((1,2), list1)  # I know this is wrong, just an example
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure you figured it out but you can use a loop for that:

```
tested_list = [1, 2, 3]
checked_list = [1, 2]

# check that every number in checked_list is in tested_list:
for num in checked_list:
    self.assertIn(num, tested_list)
```

This fails on a particular number that is missing in `tested_list` so you immediately know where the problem is.

Comment: Ofc, can't belive I missed that. Ty.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
self.assertTrue(all(x in list1 for x in [1,2]))
```

If you can use [pytest-django](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-django/) you can use the native assert statement:

```
assert all(x in list1 for x in [1,2])
```

Comment: note that if this fails, the output won't tell you which element is missing from the list

Comment: This is actually much more of a dealbreaker than it sounds.

Answer (score 3):

For stuff like this I particularly like the [hamcrest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyHamcrest) library.

You can write your test something like this:

```
from hamcrest import assert_that, has_items, contains_inanyorder

assert_that([1, 2], has_items(2, 1)) # passes

assert_that([1, 2, 3], has_items(2, 1)) # also passes - the 3 is ignored
assert_that([1, 2], has_items(3, 2, 1)) # fails - no match for 3
assert_that([1, 2], contains_inanyorder(2, 1)) # passes
assert_that([1, 2, 3], contains_inanyorder(2, 1)) # fails, no match for 3
```

Slightly more ugly, and less readable, but shows all the missing elements, rather than just the first element to fail:

```
actual = [1, 2]
expected = set([1, 2, 3, 4])
self.assertEqual(set(actual) & expected, expected)
```

Outputs:

```
AssertionError: Items in the second set but not the first:
3
4
```